# jQuery Validation: removing nearby error message onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Please take a look at [this link](http://unitedcalculator.spin-demo.com/?c=4&p=4&l=2), then click on the bottom in the lower right corner.

What I want to happen once it displays the errors is to clear the error message of the field the error belongs to. This way the user can read what the description above and whatnot.

**Basically what I want to do is to remove the error message of the required field when it is clicked. Right now that is not the case; the error message remains even if you click on the required field.**

This is currently my validation code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // validate signup form on keyup and submit
            var validator = $("#form_respond").validate({
                rules: {
                    select: "required",
                    proforma: "required",
                    date_from: "required",
                    date_to: "required" 
                }
            });
```

Let me know if there's any other info you guys need to help answer my question.

*I am not looking for another plugin; I just want to alter the current code to reach my goal.*

Comment: i am not experienced with the validation plugin, but i think the "focusCleanup" option may be what you want. it sounds like this will remove the error popup when the user focuses the validated field. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Comment: What you need is inline validation. See this [link](http://webcloud.se/log/Form-validation-with-jQuery-from-scratch/)

Comment: jbabey is correct, focusCleanup is what you need based on your description.

Comment: jbabey's solution does seem to solve the problem! Thanks guys :)

Comment: @jbabey you should put it as an answer so the OP can accept.

Comment: done, glad it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, moving this to answers from comments...

i think the "focusCleanup" option may be what you want. it sounds like this will remove the error popup when the user focuses the validated field.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Answer (score 0):

You could use a setTimeout to clear the error messages after x seconds after submission. Just look for these little buggers and do what you want with them (e.g. display: none, remove with DOM, etc.):

```
<label for="whatever" generated="true" class="error">This field is required.</label>
```